# Add UIScrollView in Existing View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

How to add scrollview in an existing view controller. I have seen many links in stackoverflow and articles and i tried to embed with scrollview but all the constraints become error (red color) and looks horrible after running the app. Can someone help me in this because i am not very fluent in swift especially in storyboard

Comment: UIScrollView has two separate guides, Frame Layout Guide and Content Layout Guide. Frame Layout Guide is to size the ScrollView itself and Content Layout Guide is to allow the content to define it's size. Usually the scroll will have either vertical or horizontal scroll. You might find this link useful to catch the nuances of setting this up in Storyboard. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/scroll-view-layouts-with-interface-builder/

Comment: as per you say you try with embeded than just pull all contsraint in bound of view controller and than set constraints

Comment: @JatinRB what i did i select the elements whatever inside the safe area then i click on editor, embed in, scrollview

Comment: yeah while scroll embded it wil show scroll view have bigger size than your controller so put those bounds in controller and than give them contraint it will set automatically.

Comment: did you get it? otherwise i will guide you.

Comment: @JatinRB You mean to say to set the scrollview constraints all 0 ?

Comment: yes, than set inner view constraints all 0

Comment: that scrollview don't have its own height  & width so bind width and height of inner view with it. it will solve automatically.

Comment: @JatinRB Can you show it please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229556/discussion-between-jatinrb-and-mohammed-nabil).

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Content layout guides option from storyboard, it'll solve your error

[image: Uncheck Content layout guides]

Thanks.

Comment: @K Shah I also tried this but still same problem in storyboard and app

Comment: @MohammedNabil thn you have to check if Botton constraint is proper